# Getting value of a PasswordBox that's inside a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have a ListView that has 3 GridViewColumns and about 10 items. The third GridViewColumn's content is:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<PasswordBox Width="200" Name="pbPass" />
</DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Can someone tell me how to get the value of pbPass for say ListViewItem no 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value should be in `PasswordBox.Password`

From code-behind, you'll probably want to loop through `MyListBox.Items`, get the `Container` for each Item using `MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator`, find the PasswordBox named pbPass in each ListBoxItem, and read the `Password` property