# Getting value of a control that's inside a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting value of a PasswordBox that's inside a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834990/getting-value-of-a-passwordbox-thats-inside-a-listview)

I have a ListView that has a TextBox:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBox Width="200" Name="tb" />
</DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Can someone tell me how to get the value of tb for say ListViewItem no 3?

Comment: Do you want to do this in XAML or in code behind?

Comment: And in C# or vb (remove the tag for the one it isn't)

Comment: Is your ListView bound to something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It easiest and most *natural*, from point of view of WPF, way is to use databinding, assigned to your control. For example:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBox Width="200" Name="tb" Text="{Binding Path=MyModelViewProperty}" />
</DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Set `MyModelViewProperty` and text will appear on `TextBox`, change the `TextBox` `Text` porperty and you model view property: `MyModelViewProperty` will be changed. There is no need to *get* a value from control, that value will be *pushed* on you by Binding mechanism automatically. Here is a simple explanation of binding and how to implement it: [Msdn Binding in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx)

Regards.

Comment: +1 for rock and roll.  The ListView is designed to be bound against an itemsource, and the items in the source should have properties that are bound to columns of the GridView that you're using.  Creating the backing bindings means that you can always access any data in the ListView's GridView by simply looking at the bound values in your item source.

Comment: (Note that all bets are off if you're trying to hammer your ListView into a scenario that it isn't really designed for.  The ListView/Gridview pair and WPF's DataGrid are notoriously difficult to use for anything but their designed scenarios.)

Comment: +1 for pointing out on possible problems with ListView + GridView. Actually you have to know what you're doing dealing with this controls pair.

Comment: @Coder:  The code was given in the answer.  Unless you're dynamically regenerating bindings, the xaml solution is the way you want to go.  Create a collection of YourRecord class that you're displaying in the ListView.  Bind the ListView's `ItemsSource` property to that collection.  Then, in the GridViewColumn's DataTemplate, bind the textbox to a property on YourRecord.

Comment: @coder: can have a look on this opensource project http://code.google.com/p/svnradar/ a lot of DataBinding stuff, what you asked for is not something that I can put in a couple of lines, but it's not also too complicated too.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the generated items from the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx), either by index or item, then you can use [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) on that item to get your TextBox.